# Datepicker methods not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm creating a filtering layout where I inicialite 2 datepickers (from-to).

Everything is working fine but I want to create a kind of shortcut button to get "Today", "Last 7 days" and "Last 30 days".

I've been trying with:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.date-picker.from').datepicker();
        $('.date-picker.to').datepicker();
    });

    $('#paymenttable_filter #today').click(function () {
        $('.date-picker.from').datepicker("setDate",new Date());
        $('.date-picker.to').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    });
```

But is not working at all. It does nothing.

I'm checking when the datepicker changes with:

```
    $(".date-picker.to").on('changeDate', function (e) {
        $("#date_to").val(e.format());
        grid.fnFilter();
    });
```

Note that I've tried use other methods from datepicker() like

```
    datepicker.("hide");
```

or

```
    datepicker.("detroy");
```

and none of them are working.

Any idea why could it be?

Comment: put all your code inside the scope of `$(document ).ready`

Comment: what is this selector `$('#paymenttable_filter #today')`   ?. Just use `$('#today')`. Ids must be unique.

Comment: Is `#today` element dynamic or static?

Comment: `#today` is a static item. And put everything in `$(document ).ready` is not working neither

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work in an example

https://jsfiddle.net/k20cpmk8/

Try just using `#today` as the solo identifier in your code and see if it updates.

Comment: Still not working.

Also if I try `$('.date-picker.from').datepicker("setDate",new Date())` with a string inestead of a Date object I get an error form a function in bootstrap-datepicker.js on function `local to utc(local)`.

Comment: Can i see your actual code because i created that off what you said and it works fine is the jsfiddle. @HectorLandete

Comment: Thanks Deckerz, but already fixed, I just replaced `bootstrap-datepicker.js` file and its working.